# mod_fcgid errors, leading to 500 error page (full details included)

Tags: php, apache2

```
[Wed Dec 12 23:23:09 2012] [warn] [client 31.22.4.214] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Wed Dec 12 23:23:09 2012] [error] [client 31.22.4.214] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Wed Dec 12 23:31:20 2012] [error] mod_fcgid: process /home/www-data/php5-fcgi(32763) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 7
```

I get these errors every times in my APACHE logs. I am running a forum, and sometimes these errors get so severe, it returns a 500 error.

I am using APC, Debian OS, PHP5CGI, and MYSQL. Here is a list of the modules I am using on APACHE:

Link to image: i.stack.imgur(dot)com/bcrWn(dot)png

**Could you please tell me what's wrong?** Is this an APC issue?

Comment: It seems that fastcgi is dropping connections with Apache. Check your fastcgi settings in php.ini. The defaults are pretty conservative if I remember right, so you might need to increase the amounts of child threads and/or the amount of client writes that are allowed. Also see if you have it set in php.ini to log PHP errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same random errors from three sites that were using APC extensively for both bytecode caching and other data using the W3 Total Cache plugin for Wordpress.

I disabled the APC caching on the sites, and the errors continued. Removing APC from the server, though, **fixed it entirely**. Since I researched this extensively and found almost no other incidences of "get unexpected signal 7" with PHP under mod_fcgid, I'm pretty confident that yes, your problem was probably caused by an APC issue.

I would imagine that you've already resolved your problem, since this question is over two months old, but hopefully this may help someone else who runs into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was also seeing this error on a shared hosting environment using php-fcgi. APC is enabled but only being used on one site which wasn't generating the error.

It turned out the site with the error had exceeded their disk quota, something I discovered by accident when trying to update some files.

Increasing the disk quota for that site immediately resolved the issue.